# Non - Polarizable Electrode/Interface

Tags: electrochemistry

Non-polarizable electrode or interface is an electrode without charge separation on electrode/electrolyte interface or without double layer at which electrochemical reaction happens infinitely/arbitrarily fast.

Platinum electrode used in SHE redox system is an example of such electrode.

However, if there is no charge separation how does SHE develop its equilibrium potential? Since developing electrode potential requires development of electrical double layer?

Comment: Developing electrode potential **different to** equilibrium potential requires development of electrical double layer, acting as the capacitor dielectricum.

Comment: Equilibrium potential also requires double layer formation, whenever there is excess charge on either phase or polar molecules it will form.